# jstat -gc pid return pid not found

Tags: java, jvm, jstat

execute jstat -gc PID return PID not found

1. After checking the directory path as/tmp/hsperfdata_ ${user}/, it is true that there is no PID file below
2. The user who starts the application process has 777 permissions to the/tmp/hsperfdata_ ${user}/directory, and there is no problem with read and write permissions
3. The JVM parameters only retain the settings of xmx and xms, and even after startup, excute jstat -gc PID still fails
4. Using JDK version 1.8.0_192, attempting to switch to JDK version 1.8.0_201 to start the application, but the JStat GC PID still fails

May I ask all the experts here if they have any experience in handling or better directions for investigation? Thank you

Comment: Run Java with `strace -f` to check if it attempts to create hsperfdata file at all. Make sure JVM does not start with `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem`. Try [hsperf](https://github.com/apangin/hsperf) tool that can read jstat counters even without hsperfdata.